# MYSQL AES_ENCRYPT issues

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I have a simple application that needs to store sensitive data in a Wordpress installation.

The data comes from the user via a Form, and up until now, I have been storing the data using `$wpdb->insert`, however as we get closer to launching this project, I want to make sure that sensitive user information is encrypted, and only decrypted when read.

I have no clue how to make this work using the `$wpdb` class, so I resorted to using `mysqli` for this component. So far, I run the `$wpdb->insert` statement to insert all the normal data, then open a new connection to try and insert the sensitive data.

```
$id = $wpdb->insert_id;

$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'wp_database';
$conn = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $db );

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Fetch Data and store it
$sud = $form['sens_user_data'];
$key = 'mysecretkey';
$tbl = $wpdb->prefix . 'sensitive';
$sql = "UPDATE $tbl SET sens_user_data = AES_ENCRYPT(?, ?) WHERE id = ?";

if ( $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) ) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $sud, $key, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    $error = $conn->errno . ' ' . $conn->error;
    ChromePhp::log($error);
}

$conn->close();
```

This appears to work correctly, except all the values always encode to a single character, and then decode to `NULL`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You really must bind all parameters, not just a few. Why are `$key` and `$id` not set as placeholders?

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't aware of that. Is that the issue with the code, is that all params are not bound?

Comment: What's `$cc` set to? And why's `$sud` unused?  Naming issue?

Comment: @Hobo, just an issue when I posted the code. $cc should have actually been $sud, I've updated the code appropriately

Comment: If you echo, `$sql` and run it manually against the database (setting the `$sud` value appropriately - echo that as well, so you're sure it's set as you assume), does it work?  Just trying to determine whether the problem is the SQL or the PHP

Comment: It's extremely important to ensure that all your user data is [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/) or you can have serious problems.

Comment: Nope. Nothing is working. I have to be missing something somewhere. Even running everything manually, I can't get things to decrypt correctly. Do encrypted fields need to be a particular data type? Currently it is VARCHAR(255). Binding all params didn't work, and echoing out my $SQL statement failed, so I went into Sequel Pro and tried to run everything manually, and still just can't get things to display correctly

Comment: @tadman, is there something that leads you to believe I'm not? Looking at the site you referenced, my code is pretty much exactly like their mysqli example

Comment: It is now, so that's great. Just watch for introducing strings like `$id` via interpolation, that's a recipe for disaster. It's probably not the issue, but ruling that out makes it for sure not an issue. You're not testing for errors, so if possible, [enable error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php).

Comment: I haven't used `AES_ENCRYPT`, but looking at [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) it "returns a binary string", so you're probably right that your data type needs changing.  According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461962/mysql-how-to-store-aes-encrypted-data), VARBINARY or BLOB should work

Comment: Yeah, I ended up solving using an alternate method described here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/replicating-mysql-aes-encryption-methods-with-php/ ... Didn't really solve the original problem, but I went and tried a few test using VARBINARY and things seemed to work correctly, so My guess is that it was the data type that was the problem